# How can I query a has-many-through relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What are some ways to query this type of relationship in Laravel

Tables:

- Users
- Roles
- Privileges

Where:

- Each role has a set of privileges
- Each user can belong to many roles
- The User has many privileges through Roles
- Users and Roles are related through an intermediate table. So there is no user_id column on the Roles table

In effect I'm trying to do something like:

```
User()->Roles()->Privileges()->get()
```

but I'm not sure of the laravel way to do this

#### DB Structure update:

```
USERS
   id
   name
   email

ROLES
   id
   role

USERS_ROLES
   id
   user_id (foreign key)
   role_id (foreign key)

PRIVILEGES
   id
   role_id (foreign key)
   privilege

USER belongsToMany Roles
ROLE belongsToMany Users
USER has many privileges through ROLES
```

Comment: can you provide table structure especially their foreign keys

Comment: I'm thinking I need to construct the query myself using the query builder, but I was hoping there was an eloquent way to do this

Comment: This is the same example described in the documentation. Have you check that ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @CanCelik it's not a one to one sample for the following reason:
 
"I tried this and the query it generates expects a user_id column on the Roles table. Users and Roles are related through an intermediate table, so there isn't a user_id on the Roles table."  In other words, I don't think the example in the documentation works on many-to-many relationships

Comment: Can you post that code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to relate `user` to `privileges` with `hasManyThrough()` method.

To do so, `privileges` must **have many** roles, but instead they **belong to many** roles. What you need here is a `belongsToManyThrough` relation that is not available with Eloquent by default.

So, you have two options:

1. Create the query by yourself
2. Use a package like [this](https://github.com/znck/belongs-to-through), which provides the `belongsToThrough()` relation.

I have not used the package I linked, but I believe it does what it says.

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, you would have the following relationship:

```
public function privileges()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Privilege', 'Role');
}
```

Then in your code you could access a user's privileges via:

```
$privileges = $user->privileges;
```

Comment: I tried this and the query it generates expects a user_id column on the Roles table.  Users and Roles are related through an intermediate table, so there isn't a user_id on the Roles table

Comment: `hasManyThrough` only works with the intermediate relationship is a `hasOne`/`hasMany`. In this case, it is a `belongsToMany`, so `hasManyThrough` will not work.

Comment: Ah good catch I made the wrong assumption a user only had at most one role. Suppose I should more thoroughly read the question.